# How do rewrite this check in C

Tags: c

I have condition which is verifing if an address is 31 bit or not ,Along side with I have to check other addess which we don't support.So Condition is like this

```
if ((addr & (1 << 31)) || (addr == 0x000f000))
{
   printf("Not 31 bit Valid address");
}
```

Now I can rewrite it as

```
if ((addr & (1<<31)) ? 1 : (( addr == 0x000f000) ? 1 : 0))
```

Now is there any other of write the same ,something which is more shorter
and unique.

Comment: First `1 << 31`  may be undefined behaviuor, write it as `1u << 31`

Comment: btw `(addr & (1u << 31) || (addr == 0x000f000)` looks good to me, add spaces for readability

Comment: Your check seems perfectly fine. Why do you want to rewrite it into something confusing?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to change the original check. What is your goal?

Comment: I just want to see some new creative code here for the same.Thats is all my goal.

Comment: There is an extra opening parenthesis in the first `if`.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar I got misunderstood from your question. It should be "is the address's 31st bit is `1` or `0`"?

Answer (score 9):

```
if(addr >> 31 || addr == 0x000f000)
```

Comment: This assumes `addr` is a 32-bit unsigned integer, which may be likely but is not stated in the question. If it is wider, additional bits may be set beyond bit 31.

Comment: It depends a bit on what the question aims at. This assumes checking for addresses that are more than 31 bit. If that is intended this check is better because it will work on 64 bit, but yes, the semantics are different.

Comment: +1 for (addr >> 31),But could be portablity issue if addr changes from 31 bit to something else.

Answer (score 0):

If your `addr` was at least 32-bit and `sizeof int` was 2, the following would work and would port well.

```
if ((addr & 0x80000000) || (addr == 0x0000f000))
```

A *better* coding style would avoid naked *magic* numbers.

```
#define InvalidAddressBitMask (0x80000000)
#define SpecialBadAddress     (0x0000f000)
if ((addr & InvalidAddressBitMask) || (addr == SpecialBadAddress))
```